# View PDF file in a new window

Tags: jquery, pdf

I want to view a pdf file in a click event of a button by ajax call and in my success i have written like this but its not working

```
 function ViewSearch(DOC_NBR) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'@Url.Action("DocToPDF","Search")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { DOC_NBR: DOC_NBR },
        async:false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            window.open(encodeURIComponent(data.ok));
        }
    });
}
```

and the data.ok will be the file path

```
"D:\Krishna\Sam\SVN\trunk\src\SampleProject\Web\SampelWeb\Content\PDF\\ENSIGN_THE SYDNEY CLINIC PTY LTD_INV_567299.PDF"
```

but its not showing up

Comment: you cannot access and open local files via javascript in your browser. also you have 2 slashes behind your PDF

Comment: Thanks what's my best option then ?

Comment: why do you need to make an ajax request? do you generate your pdfs on the fly? because normally you could just put a link to the pdf in your view?